# Wordpress.com - after saving custom CSS all widths are removed

Tags: css, wordpress, customization

I'm working with wordpress.com along with the custom design upgrade to be able to change the CSS.  Everything was working fine yesterday, and suddenly today I have an issue with the stylesheet: when I hit the 'save' button all the widths are removed from the CSS, which causes some elements to overlap or be misplaced.  It's such a strange behaviour that I don't think I could have accidentally caused it.  Only the widths disappear, every other element/rule is there.

I posted this question at the WP forums but no luck yet.  Hopefully someone here has an idea about what could be wrong.

Thank you in advance :)

SOLVED:

Apparently is a WP issue.  I 'fixed' it with a workaround that someone suggested me by replacing 'width' with 'min-width' and 'max-width'.

Comment: You should be able to move that solution into the answer field below now. Please do so, so you can mark it accepted later. Perhaps you should also link to the support forum topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was confirmed as a bug, the staff at WP already fixed it and everything is back to normal.  Here's a [link to the thread](http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/after-saving-custom-css-all-widths-are-removed?replies=10#post-848453) in case you were affected.